# Why blocks dont finalized

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot, pallet

We have substrate node with babe + grandpa consensus. We tried to run it on different computers and create a network. Everything works if we use the pre-installed accounts of Alice and Bob. We are trying to create our own config with our own keys. using subkey, 2 pairs of 4 keys were generated. 2 in sr25519 format (account address and account stash address), then a key in ed25519 format (used for GrandpaId). We took a seed-phrase from him and created a sr25519 key (for Babe). That is, we have 2 validators. We launched the nodes and using rpc requests inserted keys for both validators (babe + gran)

Nodes see each other on the network, create blocks, but do not finalize blocks. With what it can be connected? The screenshots show the config that we use when starting the network [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuysm.jpg) and second [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytUnG.jpg)

Comment: How do you run the node? Are you compiling the node with --release flag?

Comment: Don't include screenshots of text. Paste the text into your question, it's much easier to read and will help make the important parts of your question searchable.

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk, Yes, we build with --release flag, ./target/release/substrate --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --ws-port 9944  --rpc-port 9933  --validator  --rpc-methods=Uafe  --listen-addr /ip4/someip/tcp/30333 --name MyNode01 --tmp --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-cors '*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error myself, you need to remove the -tmp flag before starting, create your folders with the command -d / node / node1, and after inserting the keys, restart the nodes